# How to find the speed and acceleration of a spaceship moving exponentially towards the speed of light

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Taylor is in a spaceship that begins to move from rest and whose velocity tends exponentially to the value $c$ (the speed of light) over time. After one second, Taylor’s speed was $-10$ m/s. Determine the speed function, depending on the time! (Hint - look at the function in the form $c×a^x+b$, which could meet the described criteria.) Determine the acceleration felt by Taylor during this movement! At what point will it be greater - at the beginning or the end of the movement?

Did I solve it correctly?

First, let’s understand the problem. We are given that the velocity of the spaceship tends exponentially to the value $c$ over time. This suggests that the velocity function could be of the form $v(t) = c \times (1 - e^{-kt})$, where $v(t)$ is the velocity at time $t$, $c$ is the speed of light, $k$ is a constant, and $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm.
We are also given that after one second, Taylor’s speed was $10$ m/s. We can use this information to find the value of $k$.

- Step 1:
  Find the value of $k$.

We know that $v(1) = 10$ m/s. Substituting these values into the velocity function gives us: $10 = c\times(1 - e^{-k})$. We can solve this equation for $k$. However, we don’t know the value of $c$. Since $c$ is the speed of light, we can assume it to be approximately $3\times10^8$ m/s. Substituting this value into the equation gives us: $10 = 3\times10^8\times(1 - e^{-k})$.
Solving this equation for $k$ gives us:

\begin{align} e^{-k} = 1 - 10/(3\times10^8) &\implies -k = \ln(1 - 10/(3\times10^8)) \\
&\implies k = -\ln(1 - 10/(3\times10^8))
\end{align}

- Step 2:
  Find the velocity function.

Now that we have the value of $k$, we can substitute it back into the velocity function to get:
$$v(t) = c\times(1 - e^{-kt}).$$

- Step 3:
  Find the acceleration function.

The acceleration is the derivative of the velocity with respect to time.
So, we can find the acceleration function by differentiating the velocity function:
$$a(t) = \frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dt} = c \times k \times e^{-kt}.$$

- Step 4:
  Determine when the acceleration is greater.

The acceleration is a decreasing function of time (since $e^{-kt}$ decreases as $t$ increases), so the acceleration is greater at the beginning of the movement.
So, the velocity function is $v(t) = c\times(1 - e^{-kt})$ and the acceleration function is $a(t) = c \times k \times e^{-kt}$. The acceleration is greater at the beginning of the movement. The velocity function is $v(t) = c\times(1 - e^{-kt})$ and the acceleration function is $a(t) = c \times k \times e^{-kt}$. The acceleration is greater at the beginning of the movement.

Comment: This is a poorly conceived problem. It sets up a scenario in which relativistic physics clearly applies, then (apparently) wants you to solve it using only classical mechanics. It’s a serious framing error.

Answer (score 3):

The form of the function $ca^t+b$ in the hint is not exactly what you want. If you have a function $v(t)=ca^t+b$, where $c$ is a known constant, $v(0)=0$, and $v(1)=10$, then your solution is correct. But that's not a realistic velocity function, because, since $a=(10+c)/c$, $\lim_{t\to\infty} v(t)=\infty>c$, which is both impossible and does not satisfy the statement of the problem that his velocity tends to $c$. It is also not physically realistic, because acceleration should decrease over time, but you have (correctly) stated that your $v$ function has increasing derivative.

I noticed that the hint says a function of the form $ca^t+b$ **could** solve the problem. I would recommend trying a function of the form $-ca^t+b$. Actually, you could try a function of the form $v(t)=ma^t+b$ and solve for $m$, $a$, and $b$ using $v(0)=0$, $v(1)=10$, and $\lim_{t\to\infty}v(t)=c$, in which case you'll find that $m=-c$.

After that, everything you did with the function once you found it is good.